# Start/stop flask with supervisord

Tags: python, supervisord

I need to run a small flask server on Ubuntu and keep it up in case it crashes. I'm using supervisor to do that. It starts up fine the first time, but if it's restarted by supervisor (manually) the port is already occupied.

If the flask server is run from the command line it shuts down fine. The process does not seem to daemonize itself, which I understand can be an issue with supervisord.

```
(venv) tom@tom-desktop:~/Emotional_Mirror/emotional-mirror-backend$ python twitterEmoServer/twitterEmoServer.py 
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 133-851-307
^C(venv) tom@tom-desktop:~/Emotional_Mirror/emotional-mirror-backend$
```

Error from supervisor logs:

```
    s.bind((hostname, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tom/Emotional_Mirror/emotional-mirror-backend/twitterEmoServer/twitterEmoServer.py", line 116, in <module>
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', debug=True)
  File "/home/tom/Emotional_Mirror/emotional-mirror-backend/twitterEmoSpider/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/home/tom/Emotional_Mirror/emotional-mirror-backend/twitterEmoSpider/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 677, in run_simple
    s.bind((hostname, port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Comment: What about your `supervisord.conf` contents? In particular, how does `stopsignal` look like?

Comment: For some reason flask starts two processes, and when supervisor stops flask it sends SIGTERM to the first process. However, it is the second process that should receive the signal. I don't think supervisord can do that.

Comment: I tried using stopsignal=KILL, but that didn't work. What did work was using stopasgroup=true in the supervisord.conf file. I believe this works for the reason you state above.

Comment: Hm. Funny that that would work, it's designed for when you start multiple instances from supervisord. Ah well.